# Detect devices which are connected to iPhone via lightning port

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have an old memory stick (or a tool that works the same) with an old file system (fat12).On this device, there are several files saved as pdf, png or whatever, doesent really matter. The goal of the app should be to read all files from the device, which is connected through the lighning port adapter, download the files, and save them to either look at it via app or to upload it somewhere. (Similar to the built in files app from Apple).

The first problem I am facing is how do I check if there is something connected to my iPhone? I have seen a thread which suggests to check if the phone is charging, which unfortunatelly doesnt work because the gadged does not charge the phone while it is connected.

One approach, which tried was to work with UIDocumentPicker. It worked as i could access the files from the usb, but the probleme here is that I dont want the user to be able to go trough all files on the phone, just through the files connected with the lightning adapter and this should happen automatically as the user plugs in the phone and taps on the "Download Files" button.

I dont have a lot of code which i can show, the only four lines are regarding the UIDocumentPicker:

```
    @IBAction func getFilesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let documentPicker =
        UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"],
                                       in: .open)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: There is no way for an app to access a device on the lighting port directly unless the device is mfi certified and linked to your app. You have to use the document picker view controller or the user can use the files app.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [External Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) framework, it's [programming guide states](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009501-SW1) that it's possible to get notified about an accessory being connected or disconnected.